# How to read click multiple same href to get the value using findby element using css

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
    <a href="test.aspx?id=1">TESTDRESS</a>
    <a href="test.aspx?id=2">TESTDRESS</a>
```

TESTDRESS is found in various place in the page.

This is one which shows link.

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS,using = "a[href='test.aspx']")
```

link is not click

CacheLookup

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS,using = "a[href='test.aspx']")
    WebElement testlink;

    public void ClickDress()
    {
        System.out.println("testlink"+testlink);
        testlink.click();

    }
```

CALLIING CODE:

```
Dashboardpage= PageFactory.initElements(driver, DashboardPage.class);
Dashboardpage.ClickDress();
```

ERROR:
Marionette  INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Marionette INFO New connections will no longer be accepted

Comment: Upgrade to latest firefox and geckodriver

Comment: Done . Its not happening

Comment: dress Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.cssSelector: a[href='test.aspx']'

Comment: Can you format the HTML `<td><span id="ctl00_cPH_st" class="checked"><i class="check" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><a href="test.aspx">TESTDRESS</a></td>` as per the actual format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned `TESTDRESS is found in various place in the page` but while formatting the `HTML` you have stripped off the parent node `id` and `<span>` tags. So assuming that the `href` attributes are unique for each node the following should work:

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS,using = "a[href='test.aspx?id=1']")
@CacheLookup
WebElement testlink;

public void ClickDress()
{
    System.out.println("testlink"+testlink);
    testlink.click();

}
```

and

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS,using = "a[href='test.aspx?id=2']")
@CacheLookup
WebElement testlink;

public void ClickDress()
{
    System.out.println("testlink"+testlink);
    testlink.click();

}
```